# Swifty JSON Cloning Error

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

Can't install Swifty JSON 3.1.1 with Cocoa Pod. I'm getting this error.

[image]

I need Swifty Json for Swift3. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: check if this branch exist @Soumen can you post your podfile?

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code in your Podfile:

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git', :commit => '6a0c3a82e2b4a07723b4958146315c7928220189'
```

`6a0c3a82e2b4a07723b4958146315c7928220189` is take from [here](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/commit/6a0c3a82e2b4a07723b4958146315c7928220189) which is the release v3.1.1 that you needed